# Can I use Postgres with Angular2 in the absence of Express?

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, express

I have made several Angular2 web apps using Firebase, which is relatively straightforward to implement. My current web app will have more complex data, and I anticipate wanting to leverage the advantages of SQL-like databases to filter the data and perform transformations, etc. I’m most experienced with Postgres.

I have searched for tutorials that demonstrate setting up Postgres with Angular2, and all of them seem to require NodeJS and Express.

It seems to make sense to me that Node.js would be necessary: it performs the server-side JavaScript work (although how and whether this would replace my typescript files in my Angular2 project is not yet clear to me).

What I really can’t figure out is why Express seems essential. If the only thing I want that my current Angular2 set up can’t supply is data persistence on a server, why would another framework/layer be required for this?

Are there any purely Angular2 + Postgres tutorials/ example projects available? Absent that, what about Node + Angular2 + Postgres?

Comment: Whether you use Express, raw NodeJS, PHP, Java, .Net or whatever is irrelevant. But you need web services on the server to talk to from Angular,  over HTTP, and the web services in turn talk to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @JB Nizet does this mean that I could choose between NodeJs and Express?

Comment: ExpressJS is a web framework running on NodeJS. So, if you choose Express, you also choose NodeJS. What does the big title say on http://expressjs.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you use AngularJS/2/4 as Front End, Angular can only understand HTTP calls. For Server end support you must use any server side language like PHP, NodeJS, Python, Java or express etc which can directly connect with database.We can not do this like angular2 + Postgress